# Connect to linux device without SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, serial-console

Is there any way to connect to a device without using SSH? I've broken the keyboard on my Nokia N900 and want to get access to it. It must be possible?

Comment: Is it possible to network boot (PXE) the N900?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that... :p

Comment: If you turn your phone off and connect it to a computer over USB, does the phone appear as a USB removable drive? (Some phones do this, I have no idea if that includes the N900.)

Comment: Hmm, I'll try this, need to find my USB then! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it, but the usually involve setting it up ahead of time. Do you perchance have a serial console enabled that you can reach with a USB cable or something?

Otherwise I doubt there is anything open unless you planned for it ahead of time.

Comment: haven't set anything up ahead of time... my main phones an android phone, just trying to salvage! :p

Comment: Look into the bootloader and if there are any hooks to get into it before/as it boots.